# How to set a map to div within another div?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am a newbie in javascript and I need your help on setting a google map to div element which is within another div element. Here's the code which works if the div elements aren't nested:

```
function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
```

However if I have nested divs, it doesn't work:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="main">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of testing, I concluded that you need to set a height to your `id="main"` div also

`style="width:100%; height:100%"`

Because it's a container to the map, and without a defined height nothing will appear. It's like rolling down a curtain, the map won't push it down by itself.

I'm assuming you have something similar already too since the map works without nesting, but I'll mention it again:

```
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {height:100%}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. I was looking for the problem in the totally wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Google map need a static height and width for its canvas. You should not use % for height and width if the parent div does not have static size. Also google map has a bug that it cannot load in hidden div. (you need to have some trick if doing so)